# Linking QT 5.5 to project with cmake-gui

Tags: qt, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm trying to build a project that uses the QT 5.5 library. To create the CMake files, I'm using cmake-gui and linking to the library.By default, the program links the project to the files and directories of QT 4.X, and while looking for the same files and directories within QT 5.5, I note that some of them do not exist. (Follow the print)

It's possible to see here that there's files linked to QT 4.X and QT 5.5

[image]

Although you can build the files, trying to use the make install command displays errors like the ones below.I suppose that these errors happen precisely because of the lack of the QT 5.5 archives replaced by the QT 4.X files.

These are the error that I'm trying to solve

[image]

Here I start to see that must be a way to link the directories to the missing files in a way that there's no more this kind of errorsQT

[image]

I tried to change the directories of includes of the generated files manually, but it does not seem feasible, given the number of errors generated.Is there any way to "replace" those missing files in the QT 5.5 version?

This is the CMakeLists.txt file used for this project:

```
project(PacpusSensors)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# ========================================
# PacpusSensors version
# ========================================
set(PacpusSensors_MAJOR_VERSION 0)
set(PacpusSensors_MINOR_VERSION 1)
set(PacpusSensors_PATCH_VERSION 1)
set(PacpusSensors_VERSION
    "${PacpusSensors_MAJOR_VERSION}.${PacpusSensors_MINOR_VERSION}.${PacpusSensors_PATCH_VERSION}")

# ========================================
# Configure CMake 
# ========================================
set(PACPUS_ROOT "/home/marvsdd/PACPUS/export")
if(NOT ${PACPUS_ROOT} STREQUAL "")
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PACPUS_ROOT}/cmake)
    string (REPLACE "\\" "/" CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
    message (STATUS "setting CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to: "  ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
elseif( NOT $ENV{PACPUS_ROOT} STREQUAL "")
    set(PACPUS_ROOT $ENV{PACPUS_ROOT})
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH $ENV{PACPUS_ROOT}/cmake)
    string (REPLACE "\\" "/" CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
    message (STATUS "setting CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to: " ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
    message (STATUS "PACPUS_ROOT is: " ${PACPUS_ROOT})
else()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Environment variable PACPUS_ROOT not set, please define it in your operating system or pass it as argument to the cmake command")
endif()

include(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/PacpusUtilities.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/PacpusConfiguration.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/PacpusDependencies.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/PacpusPlatforms.cmake)

# ========================================
# Pre-configuration of the compiler
# ========================================
find_package(Pacpus REQUIRED)
# Includes directories
if(PACPUS_FOUND)
include_directories(
  ${PACPUS_DEPENDENCIES_INC}
  ${PACPUS_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
# Compiler flags coming from PacpusDependencies and PacpusPlatforms
add_definitions(${PACPUS_DEFINITIONS})
endif(PACPUS_FOUND)


# ========================================
# Find dependencies
# ========================================
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
if(QT4_FOUND)
    set(QT_USE_QTNETWORK TRUE)
    set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
    set(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
    include(${QT_USE_FILE})
    add_definitions( ${QT_DEFINITIONS} )
    add_definitions( -DQT_PLUGIN )
endif(QT4_FOUND)

include_directories(
  ${PACPUS_DEPENDENCIES_INC}
  ${PACPUS_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${PACPUS_INCLUDE_HINT}
  ${PACPUS_INCLUDE_HINT}/Pacpus
  ./PACPUS/include
)

# ========================================
# Build the PacpusSensors' modules
# ========================================
add_subdirectory(PacpusSocket)
add_subdirectory(Sick)

# ========================================
# Summary
# ========================================
pacpus_info("")
pacpus_info("=====================================================================")
pacpus_info("Configuration for PacpusSensors ${PacpusSensors_VERSION}")
pacpus_info("=====================================================================")
pacpus_info("")
pacpus_info("  Platform:")
pacpus_info("    Host:" ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION} ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR})
if(CMAKE_CROSS_COMPILING)
    pacpus_info("    Target:" ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION} ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR})
endif()
pacpus_info("    CMake:" ${CMAKE_VERSION})
pacpus_info("    CMake generator:" ${CMAKE_GENERATOR})
pacpus_info("    CMake build tool:" ${CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL})
if(MSVC)
    pacpus_info("    MSVC:" ${MSVC_VERSION})
else()
    pacpus_info("    Configuration:" ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
endif()
pacpus_info("")
pacpus_info("  Compiler:")
pacpus_info("    C++ Compiler:" ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
pacpus_info("    C++ flags (release):" ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
pacpus_info("    C++ flags (debug):" ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
pacpus_info("")
pacpus_info("  Pacpus:")
pacpus_info("    PacpusFramework path:" ${PACPUS_ROOT})
pacpus_info("    Log4cxx logging enabled:" ${PACPUS_USE_LOG})
pacpus_info("")
if("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
    message(WARNING "The source directory is the same as build directory. \"make clean\" may damage the source tree")
endif()
```

Comment: `I suppose that these errors happen precisely because of the lack of the QT 5.5 archives replaced by the QT 4.X files.` - There is no error message about **missing files**. But the very reason of "missing binary operator before token (" in QT could be mixing Qt4 and Qt5 header files. BTW, according to Stack Overflow [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), error message should be included into the question post **as text**, not as image.

Comment: what's your cmake file?

Comment: So Tsyvarev, by the time that I had access to the terminal, couldn't save the errors as text. Hope that the post doesn't get deleted because of that while I can't have the errors again.  Besides that, I do believe that I'm building this project incorrectly. However, can I assume that the QT 5.5 that I have access have missing files? In that case I would contact the person that provided me the original files to relate this problem.
  By the way, using *qmake -v*, I get _version 4.8.X_.

Comment: So, the project wants Qt4 via call `find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)` but you want to use Qt5 instead. For doing that, you have modified some cache variable show in cmake-GUI. Am I right? Porting the project from Qt4 to Qt5 is not such simple. First, do not tend to modify *any* cache entry - some of them are internal for `FindQt4.cmake` script, so you may simply break the script. Second, some Qt4 components are no longer part of Qt5. And [Phonon is one of them](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/portingguide.html). That is why you have `QT_PHONON_LIBRARY` as not found.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that Qt4 and Qt5 are being mixed here.  It's fine if you have both installed, but be sure to use the correct one.  I'm assuming you want Qt5.

A simple example of linking to Qt5 looks like this:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Network OpenGL Xml) #Qt5Core is implicit
target_link_libraries(MyApplication Qt5::Network Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::Xml)
```

You don't need `if(Qt5_FOUND)` because the package is `REQUIRED` meaning it will fail with an error if QT wasn't found.

In your CMakeLists.txt, you don't have any targets defined. You would normally do that with `add_executable`, `add_library` or `add_custom_target` cmake functions.  That means that the targets are probably defined in your sub-directories.  Find the appropriate CMakeLists.txt in the sub-directories and use the `target_link_libraries` command there.  This command will add the correct headers and do the appropriate linking for you.

If Qt was header-only, then using the global `include_directories()` and `add_definitions()` would work, but since you are going to need to link your application to Qt, you need to actually use the `target_link_libraries()` deeper down in your solution.

For more information, check out [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)